# Can I change the directory structure of a forked repository but still pull new changes?

Tags: git, github, repository

I want to change the directory structure of a repository I forked on github. I mean, I will move existing directories, create new directories and move files.

Afterwards, I want to still be able to pull updates from the origin repository for each of those files. Is this possible? If it is: How?

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. Simply move your files. I would recommend creating a single commit that only does the moves. Afterwards you can simply pull – git will figure out what to do by itself.